# Mutate dynamic column name based on others columns values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Here is how I build the df

```
df_test <- data.frame(ID = c("1100455", "1100455", "1100464", "1100464"),
                      CATEGORIE = c("10110", "90310", "10110","10140"),
                      RANK =  c( "1", "0" ,"1", "1"),
                      MD =  c("0", "0", "0", "3" ),
                      PROD3 = c(2345.00,1114.58,501.40,125.15))

newvars <- paste("aa",df_test[["CATEGORIE"]],df_test[["RANK"]],df_test[["MD"]],"ta", sep="_")
newvars <- unique(newvars)
newvars
df_test[newvars] <- NA
```

actual dataframe :

```
       ID CATEGORIE RANK MD   PROD3 aa_10110_1_0_ta aa_90310_0_0_ta aa_10140_1_3_ta
1 1100455     10110    1  0 2345.00              NA              NA              NA
2 1100455     90310    0  0 1114.58              NA              NA              NA
3 1100464     10110    1  0  501.40              NA              NA              NA
4 1100464     10140    1  3  125.15              NA              NA              NA
```

I try to update columns based on others columns values,

```
df_test <- df_test %>% mutate(get(paste0("aa_", CATEGORIE,"_",RANK,"_",MD,"_ta" ) = PROD3 )))
```

I cannot manage to make it works, I wonder if it is possible only with mutate or If I have to use a separate function ?

expected results :

```
       ID CATEGORIE RANK MD   PROD3 aa_10110_1_0_ta aa_90310_0_0_ta aa_10140_1_3_ta
1 1100455     10110    1  0 2345.00          2345.0              NA              NA
2 1100455     90310    0  0 1114.58              NA         1114.58              NA
3 1100464     10110    1  0  501.40           501.4              NA              NA
4 1100464     10140    1  3  125.15              NA              NA          125.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_c`(or `paste`) to create the new column names and then `pivot_wider` it.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_test %>%
  select_at(vars(-starts_with("aa"))) %>%  ## reset your data
  mutate(name = str_c("aa", CATEGORIE, RANK, MD, "ta", sep = "_"),
         value = PROD3) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

#        ID CATEGORIE RANK MD   PROD3 aa_10110_1_0_ta aa_90310_0_0_ta aa_10140_1_3_ta
# 1 1100455     10110    1  0 2345.00          2345.0              NA              NA
# 2 1100455     90310    0  0 1114.58              NA         1114.58              NA
# 3 1100464     10110    1  0  501.40           501.4              NA              NA
# 4 1100464     10140    1  3  125.15              NA              NA          125.15
```

---

***spread( ) edition***

If you use `spread()` then you can save the line of `select_at()` because `spread()` overwrites duplicated column names.

```
df_test %>%
  mutate(name = str_c("aa", CATEGORIE, RANK, MD, "ta", sep = "_"),
         value = PROD3) %>%
  spread(name, value)
```

Comment: I cannot use pivot_wider() with the R server version I m using right now, so I think I m gonna try with spread(), it should be similar isn't it ? Also I wonder is ths mutate syntx is speciific to pivot_wider() here because it s not working on a simple mutate, like : df_test <- df_test %>% mutate(name = str_c("aa", CATEGORIE, RANK, MD, "ta", sep = "_"),value = PROD3)  (it adds tow columns, name and value)

Comment: `mutate` is necessary before `pivot_wider` or `spread` because you need to create columns (i.e. `name` and `value` in my code) to get the name and cell values of the output column.